# Creating a stored procedure using C#, ODBC Client

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, db2, odbc

In my project I have 500 plus stored procedures that needs to be created, I have created an application to read the 500 file from the directory,

When I try to execute the create procedure via an ODBC command, I get this error:

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0104N

I am using this code:

```
OdbcDataReader dr = null;
String Error = "";

try
{
    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = sQL_To_Run;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error = $"Error Running {sQL_To_Run} => Error Message:  {ex.Message}";
    Console.WriteLine(Error);
}
```

Comment: that's a pretty cryptic error.  can you debug through and see if it is thrown on the connection or the executereader?  it seems like an bad configuration and/or db install.. can you verify that you are connected and your db is working?

Comment: @Jesse, I am able to delete the stored proc using the above code, now I want to re create the stored procedure and I get the error.

Comment: does your exception have any inner exception or any other information?  also can you share your sql_to_run?

Comment: read up on what to use for Selects vs Inserts Updates and Deletes when executing stored procedures or sql statements in C#

Comment: SQL0104N means a syntax error in your SQL statement, which you for some reason chose not to show.

Answer (score 3):

use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` because `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is for select

Answer (score -1):

If by any chance you use decimal numbers (constants) with decimal point in your SPs you will have this kind of problems if the database is configured with decimal commas or if the regional settings of the CLI don't match. You can read more about it here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21352772

Comment: I am not using any decimals, but it does seem like the issue is because the DB2 is taking the semicolon  as  termination character. Is there a way to specify a new termination character within odbccommand ?

Comment: @Anand I don´t think so. Perhaps you can insert the --#SET TERMINATOR instruction at the beginning of the script. Maybe something like `cmd.CommandText = "--#SET TERMINATOR X'5E'" + System.Environment.NewLine + sQL_To_Run; //Sets the statement terminator to comma`